# Position of a smartwatch

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, wearables

Is it possible to detect through Java an android watch position?
I need to detect the following positions:

1. watch is taken off
2. watch is worn
3. watch is connected to the charger

(3) I already have resolved, so this is not an issue only (1) and (2).

If the heart rate sensor would be of help, which output values would be the ones for (1).

Thank you very much

Comment: It is possible, yes. But ideally speaking, you need to read official documentation, *then* ask here if you have any specific problems or questions.

Comment: Thank you very much, as I am new here, can you please let me know where I can find the official documentation, I will be more than happy to read it

Comment: Usually documentation is found using the search engine of your choice (for example, Google). For instance, Wear OS doc landing page is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html).

Comment: I think I found it: "Sensor_Status_No_Contact". Thank you very much for your support

Answer (score 0):

This should work: "Sensor_Status_No_Contact".